Windows Computer Flagged for BitTorrent Traffic on School Network Despite qBitTorrent Not Running
I'm having a weird issue where whenever I am at school (and currently booted into Windows), my computer gets flagged by the school network for using BitTorrent.
Now, I do have qBitTorrent, but it isn't running when I get flagged. Now, when I'm booted into Fedora Linux, my computer does not get flagged for anything. I have looked through my running processes and my firewall (Safing Portmaster), and do not see anything out of the ordinary.
The applications that I run in the background (and on boot) are Nextcloud, Google Drive, Amazon Photos, Portmaster, Medal, whatever the NVidia tray application is, AutoHotKey, 0Patch, JetBrains Toolbox, ExplorerPatcher, VMWare, and Logitech G Hub. To the best of my knowledge, none of these programs utilize the qBitTorrent protocol.
I have also done scans with Windows Security and Malwarebytes, which do not flag anything. Other people at school use Windows computers daily without any issues, so this is not anything related to Windows. Does anyone have any pointers on what I should look at?

You could take the computer to the school IT support desk so they can observe the behavior. We can only guess at how the school is detecting torrent traffic. It may be possible to use something like Wireshark or Nmap to scan your own outbound interfaces to see what traffic they detect, though that may require a 2nd computer. I haven't tried inspecting my own device interfaces using these tools, so I don't know what's involved in doing that. At the end of the day, your school is the one detecting this, using rules and tools they've implemented, and they probably have staff able to help.


By default, when qBittorrent is closed using the Windows decoration Close button, it minimizes to the Task Bar... could it be running in the background?
Is the school performing a scan of installed software, e.g., using WinGet? If so, completely uninstall qBittorrent, and try using the portable version (when not using school resources!), either from Portable Apps or by opening the standard qBittorrent installer in 7-Zip and extracting to a folder.


No, I make sure that it is completely stopped. I'm not running any school software on my computer, so I don't know how the school could be scanning my installed software.
